# How to map JSON object's values, with another object's values when that object is having key similar to the JSON object value

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json

I have a JSON object that I want to change values dynamically with the object that comes from front end(ReactJs) which has same value as the key of that object.here is my JSON object.

```
var jsonObj = {
  "fields": {
    "field1": {
      "key": "value_1"
    },"field2": {
      "name": "value_3"
    },
     "field3":{"accountId":"value_9"},
    "field4": "value_2",
    "field5": "value_4",
    "field6": "value_5",
    "field7": {
      "value": "value_6"
    },
    
    "field8": {
      "type": "doc",
      "version": 1,
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "content": [
            {
              "text": "value_7",
              "type": "text"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is my other object that comes from React front-end

```
Obj1 {
  value_4: '896',
  value_9: '62cbef88ec233f24600c',
  value_5: 'Software',
  value_7: 'description from front',
  value_6: 'test@gmail.com',
  value_1: 'TRDSD',
  value_2: 'Test sum',
  value_8: '',
  value_10: '',
  value_11: '',
  value_12: '',
  value_13: '',
  value_3: 'TRDSD_incident'
}
```

What I want is this,

```
{
  "fields": {
    "field1": {
      "key": "TRDSD"
    },"field2": {
      "name": "TRDSD_incident"
    },
     "field3":{"accountId":"62cbef88ec233f24600c"},
    "field4": "Test sum",
    "field5": "896",
    "field6": "Software",
    "field7": {
      "value": "test@gmail.com"
    },
    
    "field8": {
      "type": "doc",
      "version": 1,
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "content": [
            {
              "text": "description from front",
              "type": "text"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Already I achieve this using this function.here what I do is first I take keys that have no nested objects into an array and check for each field.also I have same function for nested object keys and check for each in the same way( value,key,name,accountId). and finally I get the JSON object as I expected.

```
function usingTree2(obj2, map) {
        function traverse2(children) {
          for (let item of children) {
            if (item && item.field4) {
              item.field4 = map[item.field4];
            }
            if (item && item.field5) {
              item.field5 = map[item.field5];
            }
            if (item && item.field6) {
              item.field6 = map[item.field6];
            }
            if (item && item.field8.content[0].content[0].text) {
              item.field8.content[0].content[0].text =
                map[item.field8.content[0].content[0].text];
            }
            if (item && item.children) {
              traverse2(item.children);
            }
          }
        }

        traverse2(obj2);
        return obj2;
      }

 function usingTree(obj, map) {
        function traverse(children) {
          for (let item of children) {
            if (item && item.key) {
              
              item.key = map[item.key];
            } else if (item && item.value) {
              item.value = map[item.value];
            } else if (item && item.name) {
              item.name = map[item.name];
            } else if (item && item.accountId) {
              item.accountId = map[item.accountId];
            } else if (item && item.id) {
              item.id = map[item.id];
            }
            if (item && item.children) {
              traverse(item.children);
            }
          }
        }

        traverse(obj);
        return obj; 
      }

const map = obj1
var obj = Object.values(jsonObj.fields);
var obj2 = Object.values(jsonObj);

usingTree(obj, map);
usingTree2(obj2, map);

for (let i = 0; i < fieldCount; i ++) {
       usingTree(obj, map);
     }
for (let i = 0; i < fieldCount; i ++) {
       usingTree2(obj2, map);
     }
```

But the problem is fields in JSON object are changing. So instead of checking for each field how can I achieve this dynamically.Of course without using same function twice for nested objects. I know this is not a best way. I am new to Nodejs, so please help me to do this. Hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance.